# Qooxdoo large application structure

Tags: structure, qooxdoo

I want to use qooxdoo but I dont see any large appliaction example with it can anyone help me how we can structure a real large application with qooxdoo (modules, routes, events, communication)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I will try to answer my question, I was inspired by the structrue of [unifyjs](http://www.unifyjs.com/) I will create packages for data, services, ui, views in the same level of my Application.js maybe there will be a need for some mixins who will have there package too and some JS helpers as ressources, finaly the build job configuration parts will be used for application modules.

What you think? any other suggetion?